# Play AsyncResult helper not working

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have the following code in a play controller:

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Async {
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I run: `./activator compile` I get this error:

```
...       not found: value Async
[error]     Async {
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 07-jul-2014 13:28:59
```

In the docs, it says:

*"Note: Async { } is an helper method that builds an AsyncResult from a Promise[Result]."*

But so far I haven't been able to find Async nor AsyncResult in play.api._ What's wrong with my code and which would be the correct imports to get a handle of AsyncResult?

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncResult` (and all other results except `SimpleResult`) were deprecated in Play 2.2, and subsequently removed in Play 2.3, leaving only `Result`. Use `Action.async` instead:

```
def index = Action.async {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
}
```

For additional information, see the [Play 2.3 Migration Guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23), particularly the **Results restructure** section.